# R: How do I use aggregate in calculating the values for a column in respect to the values of another column?

Tags: r, aggregate, data-science

That's our exercise:

"For this task, you will be working with the LifeCycleSavings-dataset that comes with R. This dataset shows the savings ratio of different countries between 1960 to 1970 and gives information on the percentages of the countries population under the age of 15 and over the age of 75.
a ) (3 Pkt.) Calculate the average growth rate of the disposable income per percentage of the population under 15 of each country.
b ) (5 Pkt.) Sort the information you just calculated according to the growth rate and visualize it using a bar plot. Be sure to label the plot
properly."

**I don't know if this:**

```
LifeCycleSavings = LifeCycleSavings
LifeCycleSavings$ddpi_per_under15 <-(LifeCycleSavings$ddpi/LifeCycleSavings$pop15) * 100

#b
LifeCycleSavings <- LifeCycleSavings[order(LifeCycleSavings[, 6]), ] 

par(mar=c(13, 6, 6, 1));
barplot(LifeCycleSavings$ddpi_per_under15, names=rownames(LifeCycleSavings), las =2,
    xlim=c(0,60), ylim = c(0,100), col = terrain.colors(15),
    main = "average growth rate of disposable income
    per percentage of the population under 15 of each country (1960-1970)",
    xlab = "", ylab = "average growth rate of disposable income 
    per percentage of pop. under 15 (ratio)", font.lab = 2)
    mtext("countries", side=1, line=8, font = 2)
```

**or this version is the right approach to this problem:**

```
ddpi_per_under15 = aggregate(ddpi~pop15,LifeCycleSavings, mean)
row.names(ddpi_per_under15) = row.names(LifeCycleSavings)

#b

average_growth15_sorted <- ddpi_per_under15[order(ddpi_per_under15$ddpi), ]

barplot(average_growth15_sorted$ddpi, 
    names.arg = rownames(average_growth15_sorted),
    main = "Average growth of the disposable income
    per percentage of the population under 15 of each country", 
    ylab = "Average growth rate", xlab = "", las = 2,
    ylim = c(0,20), col=rainbow(50))
```

So, does the question asks for a ratio? Or what does "per" in this case mean?
Thank you!

Comment: Hi Lizyontour! Your question seems to be about how to interpret an assignment rather than how to overcome an issue with programming your solution. For this reason, it seems like this question will eventually be removed.

However, I think the answer to your question is simply "Yes": you're being asked to calculate a ratio for each country ("disposable income"/"percent of population under 15") and then display how the value of that ratio changes over time in each country.

Comment: Hi @bschneidr! Tank you very much, I know that this is not a programming question... 
Actually, we don't have information about the changes over time. So the only thing I can do is to display the ratio for each country in a barplot. Thanks anyway!